# Writing Regex expression in Hive

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, hive

Suppose the following is my data,

```
string

&geoLati=33.75875&
&loclat=39.5586&
&ang_lat_add_one_more=35.4789&
&slat=45.2563&
&LAT=12.5698&
&vloclat=65.4789&
&latpoi=35.2478&
&lat_lkj=25.6523&
&someother_lat=25.6523&
&lat=65.3214&lat=98.4562&
```

I have a long string(URL) and I want to check for the lat keyword present in the string and then check for the nearest "=" sign and parse out the value until next "&" is present. Ideally I want to write a expression which would strip off the values alone from the above data set.

The following is my attempt,

```
select regexp_extract(string, 'lat=(.*?)(&)') as output
```

This seems to work well with most of them, but doesn't work with few as well. The following is the output,

```
 output
        ""
        39.5586
        ""
        45.2563
        ""
        65.4789
        ""
        ""
        25.6523
        65.3214
```

Can anybody help me in modifying the expression in order to get all the values? I want to check for keyword lat irrespective of the case and look for the nearest "=" sign and then parse values until next "&".

My expected output is,

```
output
33.75875
39.5586
35.4789
45.2563
12.5698
65.4789
35.2478
25.6523
25.6523
65.3214
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try `(?i)lat=([^&]+)` or even `(?i)(?<=lat=)[^&]+`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the reply. this doesn't work well with "geoLati"

Comment: You did not precise the expected output. Then, try `(?i)lat\w*=([^&]+)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I just edited the expected output. The expression still doesn't work well for &geoLati=33.75875&, &lat_lkj=25.6523&

Comment: Are you sure? Look at https://regex101.com/r/DhOmxx/2

Comment: Yeah. this is the command I used, select  regexp_extract( "&lati=35.2478&" ,  '(?i)lat\w*=([^&]+)') as output and I am not getting the output

Comment: You might need to double the backslashes - `select regexp_extract( "&lati=35.2478&" , '(?i)lat\\w*=([^&]+)') as output `

Comment: Wow.. Works now. Thanks a lot !

Comment: you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: @wiktor Stribizew Can we make this expression return only numbers? If there is any text, we can ignore it? Can we add that condition to this expression? Sorry to trouble you more. I am learning regex and trying to get a hold of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?i)lat\w*=([^&]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DhOmxx/2).

**Details**:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive mode
- `lat`  - a literal char sequence
- `\w*` - 0+ word chars
- `=` - a `=` symbol
- `([^&]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `&`.

In Hive, use double backslashes:

```
select regexp_extract( "&lati=35.2478&" , '(?i)lat\\w*=([^&]+)') as output
```

Comment: Stribizew Can we make this expression return only numbers? If there is any text, we can ignore it? Can we add that condition to this expression? Sorry to trouble you more. I am learning regex and trying to get a hold of it.

Comment: The regex you want should have a sort of a positive lookbehind. Try `'(?i)(?<=lat\\w{0,50}=)[^&]+'` that will work in Java, and Hive seems to use Java regex. In Python, with `re`, that is not possible at all, but Python contains `re.findall` and other methods that allow easy access to captured groups.

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work.

```
(\b\d.+)
```

Input:

```
&geoLati=33.75875&
&loclat=39.5586&
&ang_lat_add_one_more=35.4789&
&slat=45.2563&
&LAT=12.5698&
&vloclat=65.4789&
&latpoi=35.2478&
&lat_lkj=25.6523&
&someother_lat=25.6523&
&lat=65.3214&lat=98.4562&
```

Output:

```
75875&
5586&
4789&
2563&
5698&
4789&
2478&
6523&
6523&
4562&
```

Python Code:

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(\b\d.+)"

test_str = ("&geoLati=33.75875&\n"
    "&loclat=39.5586&\n"
    "&ang_lat_add_one_more=35.4789&\n"
    "&slat=45.2563&\n"
    "&LAT=12.5698&\n"
    "&vloclat=65.4789&\n"
    "&latpoi=35.2478&\n"
    "&lat_lkj=25.6523&\n"
    "&someother_lat=25.6523&\n"
    "&lat=65.3214&lat=98.4562&")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/causfX/2

Comment: this doesn't work. select  regexp_extract( "&lat=35.2478&" , '(\b\d.+)') as output doesn't give the output

Comment: i think, you should use (\\b\\d.+)